# Disable all Notification Center sounds?

Tags: macos, notifications

I know it's possible to turn off sound alerts app-by-app in notification center, but is there a way to turn them off altogether. I hate all system sounds!

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> Sounds, and set Alert Volume to the minimum. (I'm using Yosemite, and this might not exist in earlier versions.)